# Create dtype string (not object) column from single string value without having to cast it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to create a column from a single string value that is inherently and by default already a string column and not an object column?

An object column uses too much memory, and I don't want to spend any time casting an object column back to a string column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=range(10)))
df["new"] = "my string"
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       10 non-null     int64 
 1   new     10 non-null     object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 288.0+ bytes
```

Even if I initialize an empty string column first, it still returns an object column.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=range(10)))
df["new"] = pd.Series(dtype="string")
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       10 non-null     int64 
 1   new     0 non-null      string
dtypes: int64(1), string(1)
memory usage: 288.0 bytes

df["new"] = "my string"
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       10 non-null     int64 
 1   new     10 non-null     object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 288.0+ bytes
```

This is the only way that I have found that works, but it seems like so much code & effort for accomplishing something that should be simple.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=range(10)))
df["new"] = pd.Series(["my string"] * len(df), dtype="string", index=df.index)
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       10 non-null     int64 
 1   new     10 non-null     string
dtypes: int64(1), string(1)
memory usage: 288.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. You have to use the loc method.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=range(10_000)))
df["new"] = pd.Series(dtype="string")
df.loc[:, "new"] = "my string"
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10000 entries, 0 to 9999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   a       10000 non-null  int64 
 1   new     10000 non-null  string
dtypes: int64(1), string(1)
memory usage: 156.4 KB
```